# Implementing AOT in angular 11 + Webpack 4 using @ngtools/webpack

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-devkit

I am trying implement AOT in my angular project which does not have cli support. I searched a bit and found @ngtools/webpack is the way to go. my angular is 11.0.4, Typescript is 4.0.5, webpack - 4.44.2. I installed @ngtools/webpack - 11.0.4.

my tsconfig.aot.json -

```
{
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true,
    "trace": true,
    "genDir": "aot/"
},
"angularOptions": {
    "annotationsAs": "decorators"
},
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom", "es7", "es2017", "es2018", "es2019" ],
    // "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "incremental": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "aot/",
    "app/Content/js/embed/appBootstrap.ts"
]
```

}

My Webpack.config -

```
//dependencies
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

//paths
const portalPath = path.join(__dirname, 'app');
const portalContentPath = path.join(portalPath, 'Content');
const webpackScriptPath = path.join(portalContentPath, 'js');
const nodeModulesPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const vbNodeModulesPath = path.join(nodeModulesPath, '@vb');
const outputPath = path.join(portalPath, 'dist');

//entry points
const entries = {
    embed: path.join(webpackScriptPath, 'embed', 'EmbedBootstrap.ts')
};

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: entries,
    output: {
        path: outputPath,
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        sourceMapFilename: '[file].map'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                use: [
                    '@ngtools/webpack'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader:'html-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: {
                                caseSensitive: true,
                                keepClosingSlash: true,
                                removeAttributeQuotes: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new AngularCompilerPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.aot.json'),
            sourceMap: true,
            skipCodeGeneration: true, // AOT toggle
            mainPath: path.join(webpackScriptPath, 'embed', 'appBootstrap.ts'),
            entryModule: path.join(webpackScriptPath, 'embed', 'App.Module#AppModule')
        }),
        ...Object.values(entries).map(entryPath => new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)fesm2015/, entryPath))
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
            vbNodeModulesPath,
            path.join(vbNodeModulesPath, 'vb-player', 'node_modules', '@vb')
        ],
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    }
};
```

appBootstrap.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 // This file not getting generated and giving compilation error
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './App.Module.ngfactory';
enableProdMode();

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

App.Module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './App.Component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I am using below command to run webpack.min.config (I added it to my package.json and use npm run build)

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config ./webpack.config.min.js
```

Error I am getting:-

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App.Module.ngfactory'.
```

I am not sure in which folder ngfactory file will be generated. I could not find any kind of solid implementation document for latest version of @ngtools/webpack.

I also tried to bootstrap my AppModule using platformBrowserDynamic() rather than using ngFactory. In that case I get error saying

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (41:0)
> @NgModule({
|       bootstrap: [AppComponent],
|       declarations: [
 @ ./App.Module.ts
```

I tried to play around with options in tsconfig but ended up with no luck.
Any help would highly be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you please check the latest comments of this URL - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25424 . Everyone suggested to upgrade to resolve this issue.

Comment: @AyonAlfaz Thanks for looking into it. I am using latest version of angular only but not using angular-cli. I am having my own webpack.config

Comment: @learntech Any luck on this one , how did you end up solving it

Comment: @vishnughule are you still looking for a solution for this?

Comment: @learntech Yes i am still looking for solution, i tried some other alternatives but ended up skipping AOT and my application performance degraded

Comment: I was able to implement this with webpack 4 and anglar 11. currently, I am in a process of upgrading it to angular 13 and webpack 5. what errors are you getting? I can help you on reviewing package.json/webpack config and tsconfig

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you put `"enableIvy": false` under "angularCompilerOptions"?